# How to use a filter to avoid a sub OU in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have an application that pulls user information from an OU in Active Directory.  The parameters it takes are a base for the search and a filter string.

I have an OU I want to pull information from, but there is a sub OU I want to avoid:

### Wanted

users from `OU=People,DC=mydomain,DC=com`

### Not Wanted

users from `OU=Evil,OU=People,DC=mydomain,DC=com`

I know that this could be done by rewriting the application performing teh import to stop it searching sub-OUs, but is there any way to do this with an LDAP filter on the search?  Something like (`DistinguishedName !contains "Evil"`) or similar that will let me exclude users based on the path to the user, rather than filtering on a property of the user.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using `System.DirectoryServices`(`.Protocols`) in .NET you could set the `SearchScope` to `OneLevel` to only search in the People-OU (and no child-OUs). But that won't work if you have any `OU=Good,OU=People,DC=mydomain,DC=com`...

The second option would be to query the People-OU for all sub-OU:s (`objectClass=organizationalUnit`) and then issue multiple search requests; one for each of them (except the "Evil" one).

**Edit:** @geoffc - that will be really difficult to implement. By default all authenticated users have read access to all objects in Active Directory. Just setting a "Deny Read" on the Evil OU won't do the trick because the read right for authenticated users is set on the individual user object (in this case) and thus has precedence over the Deny ACL set on the OU. You will essentially have to set the Deny Read ACL on each of the objects in the Evil-OU and always make sure new objects added to the directory get the same Deny rights set. You could edit the Active Directory schema and remove the rights for Authenticated Users but that will break a lot of other things (including Exchange) and is not supported by Microsoft.

Comment: A for effort, but wildcard searches don't work with data of type `DN`, in particular `distinguishedName`.

Comment: Deleted the first incorrect option, left the two other options.

Answer (score 12):

AFAICT, this cannot be done with an LDAP filter in active directory.  Many other LDAP implementations support extensible matching, but AD does not.

Users recommending filters containing (`ou:dn:=Evil`) or wildcards on `distinguishedName` have not tested against Active Directory.

Comment: This is correct. Active Directory does not support extensible matching: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223241.aspx

Answer (score 8):

The following will do the trick:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(!(distinguishedName:=%Evil%)))
```

I ran into a similar problem while building an address book for scan to e-mail.
I tried `(&(objectClass=user)(!(distinguishedName:=*Evil*)))` but it seems that some MFP's don't accept `*` as a wildcard, but they do accept `%`

Comment: Worked for me. If you've got multiples that you want to exclude you can do something like `(objectClass=user)(!(|(distinguishedName:=*Evil*)(distinguishedName:=*Neutral*))))`, too.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/apa/component.html, it's possible to get what you want using LDAP Component Filters. Here's an example that would match what you describe:

```
(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(!(ou:dn:=Evil)))
```

This matches all objects who have an objectClass of organizationUnit, but rejects anything whose DN contains a component that matches ou=Evil.

Answer (score 1):

The objectClasses `organizationalUnit` and its descendant `inetOrgPerson` allow the attribute `ou` to be present in an entry. Add an `ou` attribute with value `evil` to the objects subordinate to the `ou=evil` branch and include the assertion `(!(ou=evil))` to the search filter to limit responses from the candidate  list to those that do not contain an attribute `ou` with the value `evil`. Alternatively, the [LDAP Assertion Control](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/mastering-the-ldap-assertion-control/) could be used on requests in the same fashion to ensure that requests that contain an `ou` with the value `evil` are not processed. Professional quality directory servers that are LDAP compliant will support both of these methods.