# LDAP: using a filter to avoid a sub CN in Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I am trying to query nearly all users in Active Directory.
My normal users are in various OUs, and I want to retrieve those. But my system users are stored in the Users CN, and I don't want to retrieve those.

It looks a lot like [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101144/ldap-using-a-filter-to-avoid-a-sub-ou-in-active-directory), but their answer didn't help me. I'm using the hint provided [here](http://lists.fini.net/pipermail/ldap-interop/2005-February/000294.html), but its not helping out either.

I am querying in Active Directory using JNDI. My query is:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(!(cn:dn:=Users)))
```

This means all objects of class `user`, which are not in the `Users` subtree. Yet, this query nevertheless returns something like this:

```
CN=__vmware__,CN=Users,DC=SIREDRM,DC=com
```

So, why is that filter not working? How else can I make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With (!(distinguishedName=*,CN=Users= DC=mydomain,DC=com)), you are trying to use an attribute with DN syntax [Object(DS-DN)], for these LDAP attributes, you cannot use wildcards in LDAP filters.

Attribute "distinguishedName":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675516%28VS.85%29.aspx

LDAP Syntax "Object(DS-DN)"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684431%28VS.85%29.aspx

In the second link, you will find the statement about the forbidden wildcard.

In general, you could use an LDAP extensible matching rule for excluding some containers from a subtree search, in your case the syntax would be similar to this

```
(!(cn:dn:=Users))
```

or something like that. The bad thing: AD doesn't support these kind of extensible match either:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223241%28PROT.10%29.aspx
Read the first paragraph.

So the conclusion is: YOU CANNOT DO THIS WITH ONE SINGLE FILTER IN AN ACTIVE DIRECTORY ENVIRONMENT. Sorry.

The only solution appears to be to use a client-side tool. The script here from Microsoft will show you how to exactly what you need (except you want Users, not Computers).

http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/12/07/how-can-i-return-a-list-of-all-my-computers-except-those-in-a-specified-ou.aspx

The other thing you could look at is a virtual directory to act as a proxy to AD, which would allow you to configure filters and permissions without touching AD.

(mostly copied from the [hyphen site](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/File_Servers/Active_Directory/Q_25131617.html))