# Get all AD users except those that are in specific OU LDAPFilter

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We currently need to get all users except those that are in the OU "Printers" and "Cameras". We can only use a LDAPFilter for this but everything we tried does not work. Its still give use all users with those in the OU Printers and Cameras. Here what we tried:

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(!(ou=Printers)))" -Properties *
```

We also tried by doing something like this :

```
 Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(!(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=MyGroup,OU=Printers,DC=MyDomName,DC=MyDomExt))))" -Properties *
```

What are we missing? Do we have an error in our syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a filter to avoid a sub OU in Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101144/how-to-use-a-filter-to-avoid-a-sub-ou-in-active-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have OU=computer and OU=Cameras OUs at within the same search base and there are "users" in both of those OUs.

If you can NOT filter by some other criteria other than the containers they are in, you can not perform a single LDAP query within Microsoft Active Directory to accomplish the task.

If there are no "Users" in those containers you might be able to use:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```

or

```
(sAMAccountType=805306368)
```

Comment: Okay Thanks alot you assumed right, and we have users in both these OUs we just had a talk about that and we will try to find a better solution to filter this maybe by taking all users and then manually filter those in the OU by using another Tools.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(!(distinguishedName=*ou=Printers*)))" -Properties *
```

Comment: We just tried, its still doesn't work. We still dont know what we're missing. A syntax problem maybe?

Comment: No issues with the filter, it executes fine when run over Apache Directory Studio. Try executing your filter from Apache Directory Studio or jxplorer.