# Find the CN of a user without the whole DN/superordinate OU

Tags: c#, vb.net, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm adding members to AD group using VB.net. I have my employees sorted by the location they work at.

Just a quick example how my AD is set up. Let's say "John Doe" works at our location in London. His DN would then be:

```
CN=John Doe,OU=employee,OU=london,DC=me,DC=intra
```

So I'm using a loop to add as many members as there are in the groupmember array.

```
Dim i as Integer = 0
Dim Counter as Integer = tm.Length

Do While counter > 0

     group.Properties("member").Add("CN=" & tm(i) & ",OU=employee,OU=london,DC=me,DC=intra")
     group.CommitChanges()
     counter = counter - 1
     i = i + 1

Loop
```

Now my problem is that not all the people I want to add to the group are located in London. So I'd need something like:

```
CN=John Doe,OU=employee,OU=*,DC=me,DC=intra
```

But this doesn't work.

EDIT: I edited the title as I've focused another way (Query the CN instead of trying to use a wildcard OU)

So the question stand as in the title.. Is it possible to find a User (CN) without the whole DN or the superordinate OU?

Comment: This question might [help] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101144/ldap-using-a-filter-to-avoid-a-sub-ou-in-active-directory)

Comment: Thx for the link, strange I didnt found this one on my research.. (i was lacking keywords though..) I'll give it a try and report the outcomes

Comment: After some tries and further research I know now that it's not possible that a part of the DN is a wildcard (*). The solution for my problem might be to query the CN (if thats possible without the extact DN/OU). Then get the `OU=location` from the DN and then add the member to the group