# How to skip a specific Organisational Unit (OU) while getting a list of users from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, directorysearcher

I am pulling a list of users from Active Directory however i want to skip a specific Organisational Unit by the name of "ServiceAccounts". My understanding is that the following line will not solve my problem as wildcards do not work with DN :

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(distinguishedName=*ServiceAccounts*))(mail=*))";
```

This OU contains a list of around 150+ service accounts which i do not need while generating a list of employees . My only question , how to not get records from a specific OU ?

Thanks, Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In LDAP generally, substring searches within DN values are not permitted.

Microsoft Active Directory specifically [the wildcard character cannot be used with Distinguished Name attributes (attributes of data type DN), such as the distinguishedName, memberOf, directReports, and managedBy attributes.](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOSearchTips.htm)

And as Microsoft Active Directory only [supports specific Extensible Match](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Microsoft%20Active%20Directory%20Extensible%20Match%20Rules) Rules, I do not believe this is possible.

Also, by default, the "ou" value is not populated on user entries or you might be able to use:

```
(!(ou=ServiceAccounts))
```

Within the filter.

Some programing environments appear to [support a non-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101144/ldap-using-a-filter-to-avoid-a-sub-ou-in-active-directory/35022119#35022119) syntax of:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(!(distinguishedName:=%ServiceAccounts%)))
```

Perhaps providing more information about your Tree Structure someone could provide a solution.